# Make .onion websites open with tor, even if it starts with http://

Tags: tor

I want to start this off by saying that **I do not involve myself in any illegal activity**. I visit `.onion` websites for various, *legal* reasons.

Anyway, I want to have all `.onion` websites open with tor. Is this possible?

Comment: Awhile ago, the Tor bundle included [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/), a privacy filtering non-caching proxy, and there was a guide on how to set it up so that only requests to `.onion` domains went over Tor. Which is what I think you want.

Comment: Sorry, I tried searching but couldn't find any pre-built solutions. I could write a browser extension but frankly I just don't have the time. :(

Comment: Suggestion: Perhaps you might want to move this question to tor.stackexchange, which is specifically geared for questions relating to Tor.

Answer (score 1):

I think Dan is actually right on the mark. [Privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org) can be configured to pass particular URLs through a proxy but not others. This actually makes it quite easy to have it pass `.onion` traffic through `tor` but not other traffic.

You should be able to simply edit your privoxy configuration (`/etc/privoxy/config` on ArchLinux) and add the following line to it:

```
forward-socks4a .onion localhost:<your Tor port here> .
```

For more information on configuring privoxy, see the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Privoxy) and the privoxy homepage (linked above).